# Consulta em multiplas tabelas Node + Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Levando em consideração a necessidade de trazer o resultado de uma segunda tabela, baseado no resultado da primeira, como faria isso com NodeJS ? 
No PHP eu trazia o resultado, e dentro de um `while` fazia outra query passando o ID da primeira consulta (sei que naão é a melhor pratica).

//Listar usuarios

```
router.get("/users", (req, res) => {
    let query = "SELECT * FROM ??";
    let table = ["users"];
    query = mysql.format(query, table);
    connection.query(query, (err, rows) => {
        if(err){
            res.json({"Error": true, "Message": "Erro ao executar query do Mysql"});
        }else{
            res.json({"Error": false, "Message": "Successo", "Users": rows});
        }
    });
});
```

Listar informações do usuario

```
let query = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?";
let table = ["users_info"];
query = mysql.format(query, table);
```

Seria no caso esses dois, listar o usuario e listar as informações dele que esta em outra tabela.

Comment: Podes mostrar os dois SELECT que pretendes fazer?

Comment: @Sergio Editei o post

Comment: Ok, e a query é só para 1 user de cada vez certo?

Comment: Qual é a coluna de `users` que é referência para `users_info` e qual a coluna? Podes fazer isso com um `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @Sergio Sim, um user de cada vez, as colunas seria `sexo`, `nascimento`, `descricao`, nessa tabela, eu tenho uma coluna que possui o `id_user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso num só select onde juntas as duas tabelas. Se percebi bem `sexo`, `nascimento`, `descricao` são da tabela `users_info`, então um select conjunto seria assim:

```
SELECT ui.sexo, ui.nascimento, ui.descricao, u.id 
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN users_info AS ui ON u.id = ui.id_user
WHERE u.id=??
```

E as colunas que esse select dá serão `sexo`, `nascimento`, `descricao` são da tabela `users_info`, e `id` da tabela `users`.

Comment: Vou testar e ja te dou um feedback

Comment: Sergio, me tira uma duvida, com Node sou obrigado a trabalhar da forma que estou trabalhando a cima, ou posso trabalhar da forma que me passou? ao inves de ficar colocando `??`em tudo, posso simplesmente passar  direto?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto usar `??` é para essa biblioteca fazer escape e evitar injeções de SQL. Mas podes usar assim: `connection.query(query, [dados],
 (err, rows)` sem precisar de `mysql.format`. Ou então usando template strings e o `.escape()` dessa biblioteca.